# QR code reader thrown from an image of an item of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, qr-code, zxing

I want that when the image of the item is pressed launches QR code reader provided by the library zxing.

I tested two options.
The first option has been my custom adapter trying to launch the intent.

The second option has been following the first and a topic of this forum, and I got kind of my custom adapter in the main class and I created two methods.

This last option gives me syntax error, but if you run:
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) } at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1659)

Actually, this is my code:

```
public class Inventario extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    private ArrayList<Obra> obras;
    private ListView lvObras;
    private ObrasAdapter adapter;
    private TextView num, iden,ubi,hombres,material;
    private int pulsado = -1;
    Toast toast1 ;

    private int operacion = -1;

    List<String> equiDisp;
    ArrayList<String> marcado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inventario);

        equiDisp = new ArrayList<String>();
        marcado = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=1; i<11; i++)
        {
            equiDisp.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        // Inicializamos las variables.
        obras = new ArrayList<Obra>();

        rellenarArrayList();

        actualizarDisplay();
    }

        ...
    public void abrirLector(){
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    public void actualizarDisplay()
    {
       adapter = new ObrasAdapter(this, obras);
       lvObras = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
       lvObras.setAdapter(adapter);
       lvObras.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public class ObrasAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Obra> {
       public Context context;
       private ArrayList<Obra> datos;

       public void DisplayProjectListAdapter(Context c) {
       context = c;
     }

     public ObrasAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Obra> datos) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_item, datos);
        this.context = context;
        this.datos = datos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View item = convertView;
        ObrasHolder holder;

        if (item == null) {
           item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview_item,
                null);

            holder = new ObrasHolder();
            holder.qr = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.qr);

            item.setTag(holder);
    }
    holder = (ObrasHolder) item.getTag();

    holder.qr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            holder.qr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){           
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                     abrirLector();
            }
         });
        }
     });

    return item;
}
```

Can anyone help me out? Thank you

Comment: What this error is saying to you is that there is no activity inside any application with an intent filter matching your intent. This is the error that appears when you try to open an intent with startActivity but anyone is able to respond to it.

Comment: i have this in the manifiest.xml  `<activity
            android:name=".Inventario"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_inventario" >
            <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.zxing.cliet.android.SCAN"/>
          <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>)
         </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Comment: In this case, since this activity belongs to you, why aren't you using an explicit intent? Try with `new Intent(context, Inventario.class);` instead of calling to a custom action.

Comment: what? i don't uderstand you. I nedd to use `Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);` to use zxing

Comment: If you have declared an activity called `Inventario` in your manifest that is able to answer to the intent `com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN` and what you want is to open this activity, you can open it directly without the Intent filter in the manifest and creating the intent with: `Intent intent = new Intent(context, Inventario.class); intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`

Comment: it works but it is still show the same screen, have you used zxing anytme? Do yo know why it doesn't throw the zxing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92187/discussion-between-droidpl-and-user2070274).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are getting related to `ActivityNotFoundException` can be fixed by the steps you can find in [this link](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent). This is the official documentation for zxing that tells you how to open the scanner in the yet provided dialog they have. Replace it by your code:

```
 public void abrirLector(){
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `holder.qr.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener());` to the get view method.

Then add an inner class to this class:

```
private class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Main sct = (Main) activity;
        sct.onClick();
        return void;
}
```

Then go ahead and add a method called onClick() to your Main activity and add the code to call the intent in that method

Comment: So i should be two "big" class, the activity main and the custom adapter. Then in custom adapter class y write the class OnImageClickListener, Am i right?

Comment: Well since you didnt you a seperate class for your adapter, add the `OnImageClickListener` class into `ObrasAdapter`, then in the activity Inventario  implement `onClick()`. (also change `Main` to `Inventario` in the code I provided above.)

Comment: ok, i've separated in two class but i have a mistake, `Inventario sct = (Inventario) activity;`-> activity cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: My bad. In your custom adapters constructor the first parameter should be `Activity a`, assign this `a` to a class variable named `activity` of type `Activity`